# How to remove "OK" button from jQuery Alert Dialogs

Tags: jquery, alert

I used the jQuery Alert Dialogs, I want display just a message in alert box without any button and "ok" button. `jAlert('my message', 'message');`

How to remove "OK" button from jQuery Alert Dialogs ?

Comment: And how would you intend to close the dialog then?

Comment: Out of interest, how do you expect the user to dismiss the alert dialog box if it has no "OK" button?

Comment: @s1lence,Andy Holt: you don't need an OK Button to dismiss an alert dialog, you are able to close it via javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be closed, but you can remove the OK button by specifying a `callback` function as the 3rd parameter:

```
jAlert('my message', 'message', function() { $('#popup_ok').hide(); });
```

But seriously think about this, because spawning unclosable dialog boxes won't exactly make people overjoyed about your site.